# Traer x registro como primer valor Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, navegador-web

¿Como puedo traer la lista de registros de MySQL y que en primera posición me traiga x-id?
Es decir, si yo tengo una tabla con 5 registros cada uno con su id y quiero que me los traiga todos pero que en primera posición me traiga el id #4 es posible hacer eso?

De momento lo tengo con dos consultas , primero traigo la info del id#4 y luego el resto, omitiendo el#4 claro está, pero me surge la duda si se puede en una sola consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
SELECT * FROM MI_TABLA ORDER BY ID=4 DESC
```

Lo que hace el truco es el `ORDER BY ID=4`